# Correlation between a numeric and factor in R

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data

I'm new to R and I'm trying to find the correlation between a numeric variable and a factor one.
I have a data frame with the following 3 columns:
1. nr of clicks (range 0:14)
2. response (1= "YES", 0="NO")
3. Frequencies - no of counts (how many clients responded "YES" with X no of clicks)

So, the no of rows of the table is 28.

How can I measure the correlation between the dependent variable, response, and the numeric one?

Thanks!
Rodica

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine correlation between *heterogeneous* variables, you can use `hetcor()` function from the `polycor` R package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the package seems to rely on factor orderings. The package does not seem to give sensible results for unordered variables.

Comment: @HolgerBrandl It was a while ago, but thank you for letting me know. :-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485520/590437 for an alternative implementation

Comment: @HolgerBrandl Interesting. Thank you for sharing.